# SQL Function Stuck and Will Not Return Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a fairly simple function that takes a string, checks for values and replaces them and returns the resulting string after all replacements.  No loops or anything.

However, when I run it, it just sits there like it's stuck in a loop and will not return any value.

Here is the function in question:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo] (@oldStr varchar(255))
    RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @newStr varchar(255)

    SET @newStr = LTRIM(RTRIM(@oldStr))

    -- Tab  \t
    IF (@newStr LIKE '%'+CHAR(9)+'%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, CHAR(9), '')
    
    -- Linefeed \n
    IF (@newStr LIKE '%'+CHAR(10)+'%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, CHAR(10), '')
    
    -- Carriage Return \r
    IF (@newStr LIKE '%'+CHAR(13)+'%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, CHAR(13), '')

    -- °
    IF (@newStr LIKE '%'+CHAR(176)+'%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, CHAR(176), '')
    
    IF (@newStr LIKE '%#%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '#', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%:%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ':', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%;%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ';', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%@%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '@', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%[%]%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '%', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%*%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '*', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%&%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '&', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%!%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '!', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%$%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '$', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%"%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '"', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%''%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, '''', '')

    

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,INC.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',INC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,INC%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',INC', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, INC.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', INC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, INC%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', INC', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% INC.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' INC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% INC')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' INC', '')


    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,LLC.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',LLC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,LLC%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',LLC', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, LLC.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', LLC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, LLC%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', LLC', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%LLC.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' LLC.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% LLC')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' LLC', '')



    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,CO.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',CO.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,CO%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',CO', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, CO.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', CO.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, CO%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', CO', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% CO.%') 
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' CO.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% CO%') 
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' CO', '')



    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,CORP.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',CORP.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,CORP')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',CORP', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, CORP.')

        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', CORP.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, CORP')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', CORP', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% CORP.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' CORP.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% CORP')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' CORP', '')



    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,MFG.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',MFG.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,MFG')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',MFG', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, MFG.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', MFG.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, MFG')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', MFG', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% MFG.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' MFG.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% MFG')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ' MFG', '')



    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,INCORPORATED.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',INCORPORATED.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%,INCORPORATED%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ',INCORPORATED', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, INCORPORATED.%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', INCORPORATED.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '%, INCORPORATED%')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, ', INCORPORATED', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% INCORPORATED.')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, 'INCORPORATED.', '')

    IF (@newStr LIKE '% INCORPORATED')
        SET @newStr = REPLACE(@newStr, 'INCORPORATED', '')


    RETURN @newStr
END
```

I've tried a simple call with: `SELECT [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo]('Noname LLC')`

Just to rule out the fact that I'm calling a function from another database, I also tried it from the [ULTRA] database with `SELECT [dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo]('Noname LLC')` with the same result of being stuck.

I'm really at a loss here, I swear I was using this function fine before I had to wipe and reload my PC.

I'm using:

- SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2070.41)
- SSMS v18.5

Comment: There are no looping constructs in the code you have posted, so ULTRA.dbo.fn_DeNormalizeCo must contain different code... maybe even code selecting from a table that is blocked by an open transaction.

Comment: Is the `SELECT [dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo]('Noname LLC')` statement the only statement in the batch that fails to return? There is such a thing as a compilation lock in SQL, but I can see nothing here that would cause it to be blocked. Someone with more knowledge on this particular lock type might weigh in on that. Still, you could run `sp_who2` in a new window just to make sure it's not (somehow??) being blocked. Other than that... you said you had to wipe your computer? maybe a dbcc checkdb is in order. Have you checked the SQL log for anything worrying?

Comment: Oh, since you're on SQL 2019, it might also be worth trying `alter function [dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo] (@oldStr varchar(255)) returns varchar(255) with inline = OFF`, if you have the database compatibility level at 150 and inlining enabled.

Comment: There's really no reason to test with `like` before doing all the replacements.

Comment: And do you really not want anything starting with CO? You really ought to be searching for the trailing comma if this is going to work like you expect.

Comment: @allmhuran That was it!  I would never have figured it out, thank you.  Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Dizzy49 the inlining one I expect? Done

Comment: @shawnt00 True I don't need the IF's as it's implied in the REPLACE.
The CO is the trickiest of them, I'm still refining this function :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2019, it might be worth trying

```
alter function [dbo].[fn_DeNormalizeCo] (@oldStr varchar(255)) 
returns varchar(255) 
with inline = OFF
```

.. if you have the database compatibility level at 150 and inlining enabled.

Scalar inlining is still known to be buggy.